# refresh page after for loop javascript

Tags: javascript

i'm trying to refresh the page after the loop is finished. this my example doesn't work where i'm doing mistake?

```
if(this.vpb_browsed_files.length > 0) {
            for(var k=0; k<this.vpb_browsed_files.length; k++){
                var file = this.vpb_browsed_files[k];
                this.vasPLUS(file,0);
                if (parseInt(k) == parseInt(this.vpb_browsed_files.length)) {
                    var refresh = true;
                } else {
                    var refresh = false;
                }
            }

            if (refresh) {
                window.location.reload();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

You are kinda doing a lot of redundant things:

```
if(this.vpb_browsed_files.length > 0) {
        for(var k=0; k<this.vpb_browsed_files.length; k++){
            var file = this.vpb_browsed_files[k];
            this.vasPLUS(file,0);
        }
        window.location.reload();
    }
```

You don't need to do `parseInt(k)` because the variable is already and integer. The same goes for `this.vpb_browsed_files.length`

Comment: Thank you for the explanation but i already tried like that and it reload the page on the first time start the for loop. how come?

Comment: no this does not reload at the first time. try commenting out window.location and see for your self. you can replace it with `console.log('test')` for debugging